# Ansible: Error! No action detected in task

Tags: python, linux, ansible

I am receiving the following error message:

> fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "reason": "ERROR! no
>   action detected in task\n\nThe error appears to have been in
>   '/etc/ansible/roles/user-manage/tasks/add-users.yml': line 8, column
>   4, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax
>   problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n - name: Add
>   multiple users\n   ^ here\n"}

Here is my playbook that it is complaining about:

```
 - name: Add new group if it doesn't exist already
   group:
    name: "{{ item }}"
   with_items:
    - "{{ group_add }}"
   when: group_add is defined

 - name: Add multiple users
   users:
    name: "{{ item.users_name }}"
    comment: "{{item.users_comment }}"
    uid: "{{ item.users_uid }}"
    group: "{{ item.users_group }}"
    groups: "{{ item.users_groups }}"
    shell: "{{ item.users_shell }}"
    state: "{{ item.users_state }}"
    append: yes
   with_items:
     - "{{ users_add }}"

 - name: Add SSH key for user
   authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.name }}"
    key: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/ansible/files/keys/{{ item.users_name }}.pub') }}"
   with_items:
    - "{{ users_add }}"
```

This was just working last night. I'm unsure of what is causing this. Any ideas?

Comment: I would make sure users_add contains the items you think it does.  I would run:

- debug: var=item
  with_items: users_add

and make sure you see what you expect

Answer (score 2):

There is no `users` module. The correct name is [`user`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/user_module.html). Remove the `s` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error on the first line (also the name line) of a playbook. It turned out that I was using an older version of Ansible that was not compatible with some of the newer modules called in my playbook. Once I updated Ansible to the most current version, my playbook ran no problem. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: This would also seem to support @udondan's answer below, This error was due to Ansible not recognizing a module (in the above case users).